# $(2, 1+\sqrt{-5})$ invertible sheaf on $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $R= \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $I= (2, 1+\sqrt{-5})$.
I'm trying to show $\tilde{I}$ is an invertible sheaf on $\mathrm{Spec}R$.
The spectrum is covered by $D(2)$ and $D(3)$ so I claim the restriction of $\tilde{I}$ on each open affine could be trivial.

On $D(3)$, I get $(2, 1+\sqrt{-5})_3= (\frac{1-\sqrt{-5}}{3})$ as $R_3$-modules.
How about $D(2)$?

My teacher explained $(2, 1+\sqrt{-5})_2= (\frac{1+\sqrt{-5}}{2})$ as $R_2$-modules, but I found it wrong because $2$ cannot be generated by $\frac{1+\sqrt{-5}}{2}$ as a $R_2$-module.
I'm stuck here and I can't find a suitable generator.
What should I do on $D(2)$? Or I doubt $\tilde{I}$ is trivial on $D(2)$.
Thanks to your help!

Comment: You're right, but you can still prove that this is invertible: $2$ is invertible on $D(2)$, so what actually is this ideal?

Comment: Since $2$ is invertible on $D(2)$, the ideal $(2, 1+\sqrt{-5})_2$ actually equals to $R_3$, right? How stupid! I only considered proper ideals of $R_3$, and that's why I couldn't find a generator. Thanks a lot to your good teaching!

Comment: Yes, that's correct. (You've written $R_3$ once or twice there where it should be $R_2$, though.) You're welcome.